# Continuously scrolling background

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a 'Mario' Like game where the background is one image but continuously scrolls and moved position to give it a scroll affect. Currently the background image shows then shows a grey background followed by the background image again.

[image]

Could someone please help to see where I have gone wrong.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
 
    let background = SKSpriteNode(texture:SKTexture(imageNamed: "background"))
 
    var lastFrameTime : TimeInterval = 0

    var deltaTime : TimeInterval = 0
 
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.background.setScale(0.75)
    self.addChild(background)
    }
 
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        if lastFrameTime <= 0 {
            lastFrameTime = currentTime
        }
 
        deltaTime = currentTime - lastFrameTime
        lastFrameTime = currentTime
 
        self.moveSprite(sprite: background, nextSprite: background, speed:10)
    }
 
    func moveSprite(sprite : SKSpriteNode,
                    nextSprite : SKSpriteNode, speed : Float) -> Void {
        var newPosition = CGPoint.zero
 
        for spriteToMove in [sprite, nextSprite] {
 
            newPosition = spriteToMove.position
            newPosition.x -= CGFloat(speed * Float(deltaTime))
            spriteToMove.position = newPosition
 
            if spriteToMove.frame.maxX < self.frame.minX {
 
                spriteToMove.position = CGPoint(x: spriteToMove.position.x + spriteToMove.size.width * 2, y: spriteToMove.position.y)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are scaling your background down to 75%,  i do not think width takes into account the scale

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I have removed the scale and the same issue is still happening

Comment: You do not have 2 background sprites,  You need 2 if you plan on doing infinite scroll

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I've added in another SpriteNode called background 2 with the same image and changed the nextSprite to background2 although its still not working

Comment: yes, you need to put a lot more work into it lol, like placing the starting position at background.width

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in another background image and set it next to the original background image.  After that, you basically play a game of leap frog when the background is off the screen.  Take a look at the class I posted to get an idea on how a scrolling background should work.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let background = SKSpriteNode(texture:SKTexture(imageNamed: "background"))
    let background2 = SKSpriteNode(texture:SKTexture(imageNamed: "background"))

    var lastFrameTime : TimeInterval = 0

    var deltaTime : TimeInterval = 0

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        background2.position = CGPoint(x: background.size.width, y: 0)
//    self.background.setScale(0.75)
        self.addChild(background)
        self.addChild(background2)
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        if lastFrameTime <= 0 {
            lastFrameTime = currentTime
        }

        deltaTime = currentTime - lastFrameTime
        lastFrameTime = currentTime

        self.moveBackground(background,speed:10)
        self.moveBackground(background2,speed:10)
    }

    func moveBackground(_background:SKSprite,speed : Float) -> Void {
      background.position.x -= CGFloat(speed * Float(deltaTime))
      if background.position.x < -background.size.width{
          background.position.x += background.size.width * 2
      }
    }
```

Comment: I am assuming your anchor point is (0,0)  You may need to adjust for it if it is not.  Also the width of the background has to be >= screen width for this to work correctly

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I've just looked at it again and ive displayed the background but not background 2 so it's now working. Thank you